# Stuck with allignment on mobile, works perfect on desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-website

I am kinda stuck with template from W3. The website works as expected in all regards apart from one glitch on mobile browsers, the alignment of these boxes:

[Mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki6fl.png)

The CSS ID is .banner-bottom.

Weblink: http://www.finglascelticfc.com/test/index.html

Could you please point me in the right direction how to center these boxes on mobile? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome To SO. Could you please post the relevant code *in your question* not in a link.  If the link breaks your question will become useless, also remember to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Sorry. 

CSS is @ http://www.finglascelticfc.com/test/css/style.css 

I will be honest with you, can't figure out which of the mobile .banner-bottom is getting hit on page load on mobile. 

Changed most of them on the left alignment, but nothing.... :(

Comment: If you look closely at my previous comment you will see " in your question " sorry if I was vague but by that I mean copy and paste the essential parts (although the work is pretty impressive but you shouldn't include all of it) in  you post.  Links break sometimes.  If this happens this question will become useless and future visitors that may have benefited from this post may not be able to :(

Comment: The thing was I couldn't tell which @media part was getting a hit. Found it now, in my case it was:

@media(max-width:1024px){
.banner-bottom {
    width: 100%;
 }

Regards,

Comment: Oh that's good to know.  Thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center those boxes just on mobile, give `.banner-bottom` `width: 100%;`. Put this in a mobile media query as it'll mess with the layout at larger sizes.

Comment: Thank you! 

Sorted by changing:


@media(max-width:1024px){
.banner-bottom {
    width: 100%;
 }

Thanks!